# Pythonic approach needed to remove duplicates of values with varying number of strings per key

Tags: list, dictionary, duplicates

I have working code (below) but I'm new to python and feel sure there's a better way to handle this. The emoDict is the product of a long sentiment analysis process. The prior code detects and evaluates oxymorons. If an oxymoron is detected, then duplication occurs e.g. the code finds "ecstatic" and "anxiety" as separate markers, as well as "ecstatic anxiety" which are collocated terms. So, the resultant sentiment score would be downright wrong/skewed. So the logic is to remove any non-collocated duplicates. This non-collocation aspect is already taken care of, so not apparent in the code provided below. You'll notice there's a part that detects for 'not' - this is to detect simple inversions which is not an oxymoron, so I was just filtering out non-oxymoron bigrams. omitted is the process of converting the list back to the proper dict format required (geez how convoluted). Thanks guys:

```
emoDict = {'positive': 'confidence,ecstatic,ecstatic anxiety,hope,not offensive,', 'negative': 'alone,harassment,violence,suffer,depression,stress,'}
one_str = ""

for index, key in enumerate(emoDict):  
    one_str += emoDict[key]

one_list = one_str.split(',')
one_list = list(filter(None,one_list))

print ("original, cleaned list: ", one_list)

for index, row in enumerate(one_list):
    if (len(row.split(' '))) > 1:
        if (row.split(' ')[0] != "not"):
            words = row.split(' ')
            for index, word in enumerate(words):
                if word != "not":
                    for index2, row2 in enumerate(one_list):
                        if word == row2:
                            one_list.remove(word)

print ("modifed list: ", one_list)
```

it works, but surely there's a more elegant/less LOC way? Currently 20 LOC! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, the values of your `emo_dict` (stick with [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) conventions) should be lists, not strings: this is more readable and easier to operate.

```
>>> emo_dict = {'positive': 'confidence,ecstatic,ecstatic anxiety,hope,not offensive,', 'negative': 'alone,harassment,violence,suffer,depression,stress,'}
>>> emo_dict = {k: v.strip(",").split(",") for k, v in emo_dict.items()}
>>> emo_dict
{'positive': ['confidence', 'ecstatic', 'ecstatic anxiety', 'hope', 'not offensive'], 'negative': ['alone', 'harassment', 'violence', 'suffer', 'depression', 'stress']}
```

I would reverse the dict, because you have a [MultiMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) here:

```
>>> emo_by_expression = {v: k for k, vs in emo_dict.items() for v in vs}
>>> emo_by_expression
{'confidence': 'positive', 'ecstatic': 'positive', 'ecstatic anxiety': 'positive', 'hope': 'positive', 'not offensive': 'positive', 'alone': 'negative', 'harassment': 'negative', 'violence': 'negative', 'suffer': 'negative', 'depression': 'negative', 'stress': 'negative'}
```

Now your clean list (a `set` is more suitable here) is simply the keys of the dict:

```
>>> exprs = set(emo_by_expression.keys())
>>> exprs
{'confidence', 'ecstatic', 'ecstatic anxiety', 'hope', 'not offensive', 'alone', 'harassment', 'violence', 'suffer', 'depression', 'stress'}
```

The loop is basically a filter:

1. find all the oxymoron, extract the words:

```
    >>> to_remove = set()
    >>> for expr in exprs:
    ...    words = expr.split(' ')
    ...    if len(words) > 1 and "not" not in words:
    ...        to_remove.update(words)
    ...
    >>> to_remove
    {'ecstatic', 'anxiety'}
```

2. and remove them from the list:

```
    >>> exprs - to_remove
    {'confidence', 'ecstatic anxiety', 'hope', 'not offensive', 'alone', 'harassment', 'violence', 'suffer', 'depression', 'stress'}
    True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look over this carefully and checkout PEP8 too, best wishes!